# can I update all anaconda packages by manually replacing the folder of packages?

Tags: python, windows, package, anaconda, conda

I have Anaconda installed on my computer but for various reasons (firewall mainly) I cannot update my packages using the good old

> conda update --all

Also, downloading the package manually and running

> conda install [path to my file] --offline

does not work either (don't know why + I do not want do that for every single package I need to update.. just too many of them).

So I wonder whether something much **more radical and powerful** is possible: updating every desired package on my personal laptop (that also has anaconda but no network restrictions) and then copy-pasting the full folder of updated packages to my firewalled computer.

Is that going to work? I use Win 7 64bit.

Many thanks!!

Comment: If you don't have admin rights (i.e. can't write in that folder) how are you going to replace the anaconda folder? I suppose replacing the whole folder should work, but I'm not sure if the environment variables would be right. Just backup your folder and try it. You can always retrieve the original version of the anaconda install from a backup if it doesn't work.

Comment: @rth i have admin rights actually

Comment: What do you mean by environment variables?